# how to modify xlswritefig in MATLAB to use already existing file?

Tags: excel, matlab, plot

There's a function written to add plots to Excel files:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24424-xlswritefig
but it's old and doesn't work the way I need it to.

How can I adapt this code to write to a file that already exists (is being created)? For example, if I have this line that works great:

```
xlswrite(filename, percentError, 1, 'C4');
```

and I want to put a figure next to the data, I'd like to write something like:

```
xlswritefig(gcf, filename, 'Sheet1', 'E2')
```

Which seems like it should work but I get a long error:

Error using Interface.000208DB_0000_0000_C000_000000000046/invoke Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception: Source: Microsoft Excel Description: 'C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\C:\Users\User\Dropbox\MATLAB\002 Human Machine\v6_1\results_20131102_222147.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.

If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted. Help File: xlmain11.chm Help Context ID: 0

Error in xlswritefig (line 79) op = invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'open', [pwd filesep filename]);

Error in calcResults_v6_1 (line 226) xlswritefig(gcf, filename, 'Sheet1', 'E2')

Any thoughts? The file clearly exists because it was created and being written to with data, but the way xlswritefig is written (or the way I'm calling it) won't let me write a figure to the already existing file.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the return of xlswrite? Can you wrap the xlswritefig inside an if (Exists(Filename) statement? Secondly, unless it's just how you've written it, it looks like the pathname is being concatenated with another (the two "C:\"'s)

Comment: not sure what you mean by the return of xlswrite - it writes the data in the percentError variable to the C4 cell of the first sheet of the file in filename. and good catch on the concatenation - that is a cut and paste from the error, so I didn't type it, and might be the main problem. I just don't understand the xlswritefig code well enough to coax it into using the file that xlswrite already opened and not create a new one, which might be what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the call of `xlswritefig`.

- you need to put you excel file within the folder that contains your matlab script,
- call `xlswritefig` with a filename that do not include its path (just the file name).

If you to work with an Excel file that is not where your matlab script is, you need to change `[pwd filesep filename]` to `[filename]` (line 75 and 80 of xlswritefig.m).

Comment: Perfect!  For reference - I had to set the working directory using method 2 here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-17PSD/index.html (setting the path did not change the working directory when calling pwd - don't know why), but then the xlswritefig line of code I wrote above worked perfectly. Thanks!